# How do I use a photoresistor?

Tags: arduino-uno

I found this project and it seemed simple but now I don’t know. Please help. I tried changing the code and the wires but nothing happened.

```cpp
int photoSensorPin = A0;
int redLedPin = 3;
int greenLedPin = 5;
int blueLedPin = 6;
int redLedVal = 0;
int greenLedVal = 0;
int blueLedVal = 0;
boolean isLedOn = false;

int brightness = 1023;
int darkThreshold = 50;
int changeColorTime = 900000;

long lastUpdate=0;

void setup()
{
    randomSeed(analogRead(1));
}

void loop()
{
    getBrightness();
    if (brightness < darkThreshold) {
        if (!isLedOn) {
            LedOn();
            isLedOn = true;
            lastUpdate = millis();
        } else if (millis() > lastUpdate + changeColorTime) {
            LedOn();
            isLedOn = true;
            lastUpdate = millis();
        }
    } else {
        LedOff();
        isLedOn = false;
    }
    delay(1000);
}

int getBrightness()
{
    brightness = analogRead(photoSensorPin);
    return brightness;
}

void LedOn()
{
    redLedVal = random(1,128);
    greenLedVal = random(1,128);
    blueLedVal = random(1,128);

    analogWrite(redLedPin,redLedVal);
    analogWrite(greenLedPin,greenLedVal);
    analogWrite(blueLedPin,blueLedVal);
}

void LedOff(){
    analogWrite(redLedPin,0);
    analogWrite(greenLedPin,0);
    analogWrite(blueLedPin,0);
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYiLk.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Rqe.jpg)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLxSo.jpg)
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajrxT.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are some items to be improved about your question: copy your code instead of making screen shots, describe what you expect from your code, and exactly what does not work now.

Comment: have you tried outputting the analogread values via serial for various lighting situations, to see the actual measured values?

Comment: I fixed your pictures.  But you should delete your code pictures and enter the actual code then changing the format of the code using the "code format" button.

Comment: Thanks, and I’ve tried but I’m using my phone and it didn’t work. Plus, there’s a lot of code to paste on it.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Copy the code into your question, then select it and use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Firstly, instead of screenshots, use the code inserts. Also, your question title is too broad, if you are having a problem list that.

Comment: Thank you @EjarisAbu-khdeir for entering you code instead of using pictures of your code.  It make it much easier to read and help you.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set set the pins to output mode. In `setup()`, add:

```cpp
pinMode(redLedPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(greenLedPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(blueLedPin, OUTPUT);
```

If that doesn't work, then you will need some debugging. Add also this
to `setup()`:

```cpp
Serial.begin(9600);
```

and this to `loop()`:

```cpp
Serial.println(brightness);
```

Look at the values printed. Do they vary significantly when the lighting
conditions change? If not, check the wiring of the LDR (it is fine in
your schematic). Do they go below and above `darkThreshold`? If not,
then change your threshold.

Answer (score 0):

How fast does this project need to be for it to be useful?  A [photo resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) can take as much as a second to react to bright to dark conditions.

> Photoresistors also exhibit a certain degree of latency between
> exposure to light and the subsequent decrease in resistance, usually
> around 10 milliseconds. The lag time when going from lit to dark
> environments is even greater, often as long as one second. This
> property makes them unsuitable for sensing rapidly flashing lights

Consider testing the code by connecting A0 to 5 volts to simulate a bright condition.  Then connect A0 to ground to simulate a dark condition.

Comment: I don’t believe that the problem is the code. I’m very certain that it’s wiring. I even added a 2k resistor but I’m not sure how to wire it to the project.

Comment: The above answer has nothing to do with the code.  A photo resistor can have a very long on to off time.  How fast do you need to detect an on to off event?   Are you trying to detect a flashing light?  It may not work.  Are you trying to tell the difference between day and night.  That will probably work.

Comment: @EjarisAbu-khdeir Your wiring (as shown in the schematic) looks like it should work. If you're debugging the code it's always helpful to put some `Serial.print(...)` statements in there to see if it's really doing what you intended. Have you tried to output the values that come from the LDR input to see how it reacts to light and what value the threshold should have? You could also print something when your code turns the LEDs on or off (to see if that is really happening when you want it to happen).

Comment: Thank you @StarCat for actually trying to answer the question. It’s not the code but the wiring. Here, I’ll add another picture.

Comment: Also @StarCat, I tried adding code like that but it just did the same thing, nothing. The photoresistor isn’t connecting to the RGB.

Comment: @EjarisAbu-khdeir, to be absolutely clear, I am not commenting on your code at all.  I am just asking how fast you need the electronics to work.  I ask because a photo resistor can not detect fast flashing lights.  A photo resistor can only be used to detect light level changes that take longer then about a second.

Comment: @st2000 I need it to function correctly, I don’t care how fast it runs.

Comment: @EjarisAbu-khdeir, I hope you are not angry.  And I hope your project works as you want it to.

Comment: @st2000 I’m not mad and thank you, I’m just frustrated with this project and I don’t understand how to make it function.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet how do you change darkthreshold?

Comment: I think Edgar Bonet wanted you to first print out the value you are getting for brightness with the lights on and with the lights off.  Then to change this line "int darkThreshold = 50;"  from 50 to a number in between the value you are getting for brightness when the light are on and for brightness when the lights are off.